# Why in Vanilla Gradient for saliency map, we set other classes to zero?

Tags: neural-networks, explainable-ai, saliency-map

I am reading [Pixel Attribution (Saliency Maps)](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/pixel-attribution.html) and I have stumbled on the following.

For the Vanilla Gradient, if we want to calculate the saliency map for image $I$, then we start with the following steps:

1. Forward pass of $I$.
2. Compute the gradient of class score of interest with respect to $I$, **and set all other classes to 0**.

Why we need to set all the other classes to 0? Assuming a grayscale image of size $H\times W$, and a multioutput neural network of $k$ classes, the gradient of the output with respect to the input is a tensor of shape $k \times H \times W$.

Why not just simply take the "slice" of the tensor that corresponds to the gradient with respect to the class of interest?

Can someone explain the reasoning behind setting all other classes to 0 and how we achieve it in practice?